# What does "represented" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm watching the movie "The Beach", from the year 2000, and in one of the scenes, a group of people living together, is having their nightly routine of learning a phrase from a foreign language, and some people are selected who need to repeat the phrase that someone suggested, in their respective language. This time the choice falls on the character played by Leonardo Dicaprio. This is the first time he has to do this, and he is a little nervous. With a shaking voice, he repeats slowly and hesitantly the phrase "sutra cu putovati mnogo milja biciklom". It turns out he nails it on the head. The group is cheering for him and one of the leaders of the group gives him an approving gesture and says: "Yes, Richard! **Represented** Man!"

Represent (source: Urban Dictionary)
To give homage to where your from, usually with a nickname like Motor City, an area code like 305 or just saying the name like The Bronx.
I represent New Jersey and Manhattan

Does he mean that because Richard made a good answer he represented his country and therefore payed his homage?

Comment: I guess? This colloquial use of "represent" doesn't always have to make clear what group is being "represented," simply that the person "made a good showing," as the British might say.

Comment: That definition from Urban Dictionary makes no sense to me (and it should be _you're from_).

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but I suspect the line would be better written as "Represented, man!"

Comment: @STRANGDON And what would that mean? Can you say that when someone does something well, as a sign of approval?

Comment: @StaticBounce It doesn't really change the meaning, it's just that "man" is a form of address that you might use in place of someone's name.

Comment: I didn't say it changes a meaning, it was someone else. I just want to know what it means in this context but I'm having troubles getting the answer. Tell me, and if it changes the meaning tell me both of them.

Comment: According to other sources it's "you're represented, man!", so this question might rely on misinterpretation.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, I think that the transcription works better with a comma, because "man" seems to be a vocative:

> "Yes, Richard! Represented, man!"

M-W gives [the following definition of "represent"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/represent):

> *slang* : to perform a task or duty admirably : serve as an outstanding example

In that case, [the subject would have been omitted](https://slate.com/human-interest/2016/05/all-your-questions-about-pronoun-deletion-and-the-inexorable-death-of-the-universe-answered.html):

> "Yes, Richard! [[You]] represented, man!"

Answer (score 0):

What@stangdon has suggested, adding a comma after **Represented**, makes sense.

> "Yes, Richard! Represented, Man!"

The nearest definition for **represent** I found in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/represent) says

> to be something or to be **equal to** something [emphasis added]:

> This sum of money represents a large percentage of our working capital.

**Represented** in that highly condensed remark from that leader hence could mean the phrase Leonardo Dicaprio repeated in his language was **equal to** the original.